# Instance Functions vs Class Functions in Ruby

Tags: ruby, include, require

I have two versions of a simple program that accomplishes the same thing. I have some questions.

1. When should I use class functions over instance functions?
2. Are there any performance benefits of using class vs instance functions? Does one use more resource than the other given everything else constant.
3. Is defining a class function with self the same as defining it with the module's name (version 2 question)

**Version 1: instance functions**

I have a file called pastries.rb that contains:

```
module Pastries
  def description
    return "I am a pastry!"
  end
end
```

Then in another file called main.rb, I have:

```
require 'pastries'
include Pastries
puts "With include: #{description}" # With include: I am a pastry!
```

**Version 2: class functions**

pastries.rb:

```
module Pastries
  # Are the following equivalent?

  # def self.info 
  #   return "I am a pastry!"
  # end

  def Pastries.description
    return "I am a pastry!"
  end
end
```

main.rb:

```
require 'pastries'
puts "WITHOUT include: #{Pastries.description}" # WITHOUT include: I am a pastry!
```

Any feedback is appreciated. I am a newbie both on stackoverflow and in Ruby, so correction of posting style or other critiques are welcomed as well.

Comment: The example shows a module two times. First you use it as a mixin and second as a namespace. That are the use cases of modules I guess. The desicion depends on how you want to use the module in first place.

Comment: Any feedback on questions 2 and 3?

Comment: 2 - I've no idea, Performance/Footprint also depends on your environment (MRI/Jruby/etc); 3 - It's the same but `self` also works after renaming the module.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To start off, functions in Ruby are called Methods.

In version 1, you are using the Module with an instance method, which can be used in mixins (i.e., it is mixed in to a class) as above. Here, you are mixing it with the top-level object class in main.rb.

In version 2, you are using the Module(s) with class method(s), where the module acts as a namespace to avoid namespace collisions for these methods when it is used along with other modules and classes.

To your particular questions:

## 1. When should I use class functions over instance functions?

Class level methods within modules may be used when you want to provide direct access to a module's methods without the need of instantiating a class object (for ex. standalone libraries) or when you want to use the method in the scope of the object where it is mixed in.

Instance methods should be used when you want to call the module's method via a class object where it is mixed in (for ex. to provide additional functionality for a class and serve a mechanism for a class similar to multiple inheritance)

## 2. Are there any performance benefits of using class vs instance functions? Does one use more resource than the other given everything else constant.

As explained in 1 and 3, the benefits depend on the required usage. For memory consumption, AFAIK, no countable differences.

## 3. Is defining a class function with self the same as defining it with the module's name (version 2 question)

Not exactly. When you define a module method with module's name, it'll always be accessible in the scope of the module, while a module method defined with self will be accessed in the scope of the object from where it has been called. See the following answer for a detailed description: [Trying to understand use of self.method_name vs. Classname.method_name in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863782/trying-to-understand-use-of-self-method-name-vs-classname-method-name-in-ruby)

Hope this helps, Cheers.

Comment: I guess your third explaination isn't correct. I found no reference under the linked ressource about the scoping you mentioned. Could you provied a conrete example?

Comment: Thanks, that clarified it.